# Join tables in view OR create table from join, then view on top?

Tags: sql, database, netezza

Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms for this, but I'm trying to understand if there's a difference between view vs. table query performance in Netezza. I have an Inventory view, which also considers Currency, that has grown to nearly 2B records since inception several years ago. The view is created by joining several tables and query performance has degraded over time. I'm wondering if it would help to create a new physical table that does the joins the view is currently doing and then create my new view as basically a "SELECT * FROM [THIS_NEW_TABLE]". Would this new view then theoretically perform better than the original one, where the joins are in the view? I know I can test this to see the results, but I'm trying to understand why one would be better than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "yes", at least under most circumstances.  Selecting from a base table versus a view has these advantages:

- The engine only has to read the data in the columns of the resulting table.  With a view, additional columns may need to be read.
- The engine has accurate statistics on the resulting table, which can be used for the rest of the query.
- The resulting table can be indexed to further speed queries that use it.

The downside, of course, is that the table is immediately out of date when new data is inserted into (or updated in or deleted from) the base tables.  If you can live with that problem -- say by recreating the table once per day or once per week -- then you should see a performance improvement.

Some databases offer materialized views to overcome this issue.  Alas, Netezza restricts materialized views to a single table, so that doesn't particularly help you.

Comment: Does Netezza allow for the use of triggers to automatically update/insert new information into the table?  And would that be an acceptable option for this or would you use a scheduled job or would you recommend something different?  Even though I didn't ask the question I'm still curious as what would be ideal in this situation.

Comment: @Dresden . . . Probably the ideal is to recreate the table on a schedule, say once per day.  But that might be ideal under all circumstances.

Comment: Yes, the table would be recreated daily. Thanks for the input!